# Anchor down depending an array and have section highlighted in menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, twitter-bootstrap, scroll

I have a function that should drop the page to a section of the page where it matches the data attributes `data-target` and `data-index` (function one)

however this function dose not highlight the current section you scrolled on in the menu.

As you can see by my bad attempt `$(this).addClass('menuFollower-t');` I have tried to set a class to emulate this effect how ever it dose not work as hoped and only works on click and is not removed.

If someone can please help me add a class so that when the scroll or section item is clicked that the menu shows this.

**Function one**

```
_pdpNavigationScrollTo = function () {
        _pdpLink.on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var _fixedNavHeight, _target, _target_index, _scrollTopPixels;

            if (!INFORMA.global.device.isDesktop) {

                _target = $(this).data('target');
                _target_index = $(this).data('target-index');

                $('#pdp-sections').slideUp();
                _pdpNavigationHeight = $('#pdp-navigation .nav-pdp-nondesktop').outerHeight();


                if (!_pdpFixed)
                    _pdpSectionsHeight = $('#pdp-sections').height();
                else
                    _pdpSectionsHeight = 0;

                _fixedNavHeight = _navHeightMobile;
                var anchorElementArray = $("[id='" + _target + "']");

                // console.log(anchorElementArray[_target_index]);

                if (anchorElementArray.length >= [_target_index]) {
                    //Fix ben-2018-onscroll
                    _scrollTopPixels = $(anchorElementArray[_target_index]).offset().top - (_fixedNavHeight + _pdpNavigationHeight + _pdpSectionsHeight);
                    //End
                    // console.log(.offset)
                } else {
                    _scrollTopPixels = $("#" + _target).offset().top - (_fixedNavHeight + _pdpNavigationHeight + _pdpSectionsHeight);
                }
                $('html, body').stop().animate({
                    scrollTop: _scrollTopPixels
                }, 1000);

            } else {
                $('#pdp-navigation li').removeClass('selected');
                $('#pdp-navigation li').addClass('select-options');
                _pdpNavigationHeight = _pdpNavigation.height();
                _target = $(this).data('target');
                _target_index = $(this).data('target-index');
                _fixedNavHeight = _navHeightMobile;
                var anchorElementArrayDesk = $("[id='" + _target + "']");

                if (anchorElementArrayDesk.length >= [_target_index]) {
                    //Fix ben-2018-onscroll
                    _scrollTopPixels = $(anchorElementArrayDesk[_target_index]).offset().top - (_fixedNavHeight + _pdpNavigationHeight);
                    //End
                     $(this).addClass('menuFollower-t');
                } else {
                    _scrollTopPixels = $("#" + _target).offset().top - (_fixedNavHeight + _pdpNavigationHeight);
                }
                $('html, body').stop().animate({
                    scrollTop: _scrollTopPixels
                }, 1000);
            }

        })
    };
```

Function two is a old function that is no longer used but used, but it was to build a menu based on data, Function two has the section highlight in the menu working. Ive tried for hours to get this to work with the new function just to get the menu section working to no success.

any help is much appreciated.

**Function Two**

```
 $('.pdp-item-id').each(function() {
          var _Id = $(this).attr("id");
          for(var i = 0; i < _ArrayOfPdpElements.length; i++) {
              if(_ArrayOfPdpElements[i].Target === _Id) {
                  Html += '<li><a href="#" data-target="' +_ArrayOfPdpElements[i].Target+ '"><span>' +_ArrayOfPdpElements[i].Name+ '</span></a></li>';
              }
          }
      })
```

Comment: can you provide a working example?

Comment: I can try, its so tightly coupled together but ill give it a go